# Why Multi Kafka Consumer Object makes it always rebalancing, and not work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In the past, I made the wrong decision, that is, operating multiple consumers in a thread (same group id), but there was no corresponding usage scenario at the time, so this problem was not revealed.

Now, I realize that my program will go wrong when I have multiple consumers, query the corresponding information, plus my own test, I got these three scenarios.

1. Within one thread, multiple consumers with the same group id cannot work normally.
2. Within a thread, multiple consumers with different group ids can work normally.
3. run 2's program with single cpu, it works normally.

I think I know how to change it, but I don't know why, what kind of things kafka consumers store in the thread will lead to this situation.

my code is like this

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "3000");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "500");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "shoothzj.group");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return properties;



private Map<String, KafkaConsumer<String, T>> consumerMap = new HashMap<>();


for (KafkaConsumer<String, T> consumer :consumerMap.values()) {
                    consumer.poll(1000);
//handle it
                }
```

Comment: Please show your consumerMap and the Properties loaded into each consumer. See [mcve]

Comment: I figure out a reason, haven't know if it's right. Because my consumers all have the same groupId, when a new consumer joins, it triggers a rebalance. This operation requires all consumers to handle it during the poll, which constitutes a problem similar to deadlock.

Comment: Sure. Though, it's not clear where you're ever adding consumers into the group

Comment: @S.Hzj I have the same problem
Can you explain more about it?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, my English is not good. I was simply add consumer to the map. The reason using map is just want to close the consumer according to id.

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi when you add a consumer, it will trigger rebalancing. In this process, consumer's poll can't work normally. It will wait for all the same group id consumer do thing (like commit new consumer in). But now, you put all the consumer in a thread. Dead Lock

Comment: If you want multiple consumers that you can close by id, try a `Map<Integer, Thread>`. In each thread, holds a consumer, and you can implement a stop method on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple consumers with same group id in the same thread. Below is the excerpt from the book `Kafka: The Definitive Guide`

> You can’t have multiple consumers that belong to the same group in one
>   thread and you can’t have multiple threads safely use the same
>   consumer. One consumer per thread is the rule. To run multiple
>   consumers in the same group in one application, you will need to run
>   each in its own thread. It is useful to wrap the consumer logic in
>   its own object and then use Java’s ExecutorService to start multiple
>   threads each with its own consumer. The Confluent blog has a
>   tutorial that shows how to do just that.

We faced a similar issue in one of our design, and learnt our lesson the hard way. If I remember the root cause correctly, it was something like this. Let's say there are two consumers in the same thread. If the processing after the first poll takes *long* time, the second consumer might fail to send the heartbeat to the *groupcoordinator*, as sending of heartbeat happens in the *poll()* method, and that would trigger rebalance, and this will cause a deadlock like situation. So, both your consumers would get stuck, waiting for re-balancing to finish.